# Appending an element with onclick / (click) attribute in TypeScript / NativeScript / Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

**I searched other answers on this before** but unfortunately none of them addressed the solution as I needed it. What happens is that I am trying to append the following in my `component.ts` file:

```
 var to_append = "<input onclick='dosomething()'/>"
```

And while the element **is** appended (via pure javascript) the onclick/(click) property of it won't work (and I understand why, because it does not go through the supposed compiler) but the problem is `$compiler` is checking out as undefined in my code so I can't really do `$scope(append...` or similar as solutions suggested in other questions, considering how angular turns the up structure to something as seen below:

```
<input _ngcontent-ccn-6></input>
```

Any ideas on this one? I need a solution that applies to any element and is suitable for an Angular 2 environment.

Comment: I can only imagine `doSomething()` working if the function is on the global context. What happens if you open the developer console, and enter `doSomething();` right there?

Comment: Both `$scope` and `$compile` are Angular 1.* services. Angular 2 does not carry these concepts forward. Angular 2 did have at one point a `DynamicComponentLoader`. That may be a great place to start.

Comment: @Katana314 nothing happens or undefined. The function is not recognized.

Comment: OK - I may have missed that you already knew that part. Sorry, I don't think I know of any Angular 2 feature that would let you generically evaluate and insert HTML. Sean's comment seems on-point.

Comment: We might need to know more - your code samples indeed refer to angular1, not 2 and what you want to append isn't a valid native script component. Can't you have your layouts set up for *ngFor and when you want to add a new element on the page, just push it to the iterated collection ?